# Undefined variable $id Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function

Issue: Warning: Undefined variable $id in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/themename/functions.php on line 78

Issue:

```
add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 92;});
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_custom_thumbnail_size' );
function mytheme_custom_thumbnail_size(){
    add_image_size( 'thumb-small', 100, 56, true );
    add_image_size( 'thumb-medium', 190, 9999 );
    add_image_size( 'thumb-large', 400, 225 );
}
get_the_post_thumbnail($id, array(200,200) ); (This is line 78. Any suggestions. Using Wordpress 6.1.1)
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

I have not tried anything. It wont let me theme show up.

Comment: You need to either pass the ID of thumbnail or remove the code, I think better to remove the code might be added by mistake

Answer (score -1):

you could specify $id to fix the problem like this:

```
$id = get_the_ID();
get_the_post_thumbnail($id, array(200,200) );
```

or, failing that I'd suggest commenting that line out like this with two /

```
//get_the_post_thumbnail($id, array(200,200) );
```

This should fix the issue and allow you to figure out if it was needed.

Comment: Looks like even though someone said it was not useful upon adding it seemed to easy its pain. Thanks. I did wp debugging and it gone for now.